# Text from Textbox to char* (converting/marshal)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, marshalling, managed-c++

Currently I'm busy to get some text from the textbox and then convert in into a const char*. I have the following code:

```
System::String^ host = textBoxHostadres->Text;
    const char* host2 = (const char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(host);
    //system(host2); //What to do with this?
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(host2);
```

It gives a redline (Visual Studio 2012) under *`Marshal::FreeHGlobal`*. Can somebody give me a right direction to get the text from the `textbox` and get it to a `const char*`? The first line works well and through debugging I see the text get captured.

Update:

```
System::String^ host = textBoxHostadres->Text;
                pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(host);

            // Convert to a char*
            size_t origsize = wcslen(wch) + 1;
            const size_t newsize = 100;
            size_t convertedChars = 0;
            char nstring[newsize];
            wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, nstring, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
            strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");

            const char* host2 = (const char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(host);
            system(host2);

            traceroute hostAddress(host2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28VS.80%29.aspx) you will find all possible conversion between **char *, wchar_t*, _bstr_t, CComBSTR, CString, basic_string, and System.String.**

> The strings types that are covered include char *, wchar_t*, _bstr_t, CComBSTR, CString, basic_string, and System.String. In all cases, a copy of the string is made when converted to the new type. Any changes made to the new string will not affect the original string, and vice versa.

Regarding the EDITs you've added:

It would be nice if you could at least try to understand the code you are copy-pasting. This line `strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");` adds some characters to your string and mainly `(char *)` and this is obvious now that your `nstring` doesn't contain an adress of a file allready, but adress + some trash. Also you don't need this line `std::cout << nstring << std::endl;` at all.

This is how your implementation should look like.

```
System::String^ host = textBoxHostadres->Text;
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(host);
// Convert to a char*
size_t origsize = wcslen(wch) + 1;
const size_t newsize = 100;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
char nstring[newsize];  // nstring is an array of chars
wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, nstring, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
// strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");  this line adds trash to your nstring!!!
traceroute hostAddress(nstring);
```

Comment: I have updated my post, related to your answer above. How can can it be, that nstring is empty? I need the addres filled in to start a traceroute

Comment: The last line is indeed not necessary, but it is handy to see what is printed out (debugging). I have updated my c++ code. This should do it. Only I still get an error, with that seems to do it with Boost::Asio.

Comment: @computergek92 so you are converting your `host` to `nstring` and you never use `nstring` again... Remove `strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");` and write `traceroute hostAddress(nstring);`

Comment: And for a String^ to int? On the listed MSDN website there is no information about it. On the internet there is only  a lot of static casting

Comment: @computergek92 well you make a `string` out of `String^` and then use `std::stoi`.

Comment: I have made this: System::String^ maxTTL = textBoxMaxTTL->Text;
std::string bla = marshal_as<std::string>(maxTTL);
int maxTTL2 = atoi(bla.c_str()); But I stays '0'. I will try std::stoi

Comment: I think you should try posting the issue you are having in a separate Q&A it is hard to understand from here what the actual problem is.

Comment: I will do that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341479/text-from-textbox-covert-from-string-to-int

Answer (score 0):

You were not type-casting `host2` in your call to `Marshal::FreeHGlobal()`:

```
System::String^ host = textBoxHostadres->Text;
const char* host2 = (const char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(host);
system(host2);
traceroute hostAddress(host2);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr) host2);
```