# Text from Textbox covert from String^ to int

Tags: string, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, converters

Currently I'm making an application and try to get a value from a textBox and convert it then to an integer for further use. I have the following code:

```
System::String^ maxTTL = textBoxMaxTTL->Text; 
std::string bla = marshal_as<std::string>(maxTTL); //System string^ to std::string
int maxTTL2 = std::atoi(bla.c_str());
```

It seems that maxTTL2 still got the value of '0'. When I use the `stoi` argument it throws the following exception: stoi argument out of range. Has somebody an idea to resolve this?

Comment: Can't you just change the type of maxTTL to something like `System::Int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
int i = Int32::Parse(maxTTL);
```

Afterwards you will get the int in `i`. You can also bulletproof the code with a try block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `std::stoi()` as you have a `std::string` type to convert to `int`.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) is the documentation you need for `std::stoi()`.

So your line should look like: `int maxTTL2 = std::stoi(bla);`

Comment: Barbaroise Yes I think indeed that std:stoi() is necessary, but it is strange that it gives the exception:  `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in (projectname). Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.` In the of stoi: `stoi argument out of range`

Comment: Read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) under **Exceptions** one of those is your problem.

Comment: This works also! The problem was that the textBox was cleared somewhere in the code,...